# "MediaQuery.of(context).size" VS "LayouBuilder( BoxConstraints constraints)"

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, mpmediaquery, flutter-layoutbuilder

I am a new Flutter learner. I am trying to write both mobile and web application using the same code base. I am wondering to know where should I use `MediaQuery.of(context).size` and where `LayouBuilder( BoxConstraints constraints)`?

Also like to know is it efficient to only one of them all through a big application or they are kind of complementary to each other?

EDIT: I like also know more about the behavior of these methods while

- User zoom-in/zoom-out the screen
- User changes the orientation of the screen on the mobile app, or the web browser size on the desktop computer

Which method is more suitable for these 2 situations?

Answer (score 11):

`LayoutBuilder` provide constrains based on its parent widget. You can wrap `LayoutBuilder` with a SizedBox, then check the constraints of it.

But for the `MediaQuery.of(context).size` it will provide the screen size, doesnt matter it is wraped with a SizedBox or not.

- To get screen size inside widget tree, you can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size`,*The size of the media in logical pixels (e.g, the size of the screen).*
- To get parent widget size, and layout inner children based on parent, use `LayouBuilder`

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) {
              return Container(
                width: constraints.maxWidth,
                height: constraints.maxHeight,
                color: Colors.red.withOpacity(.3),
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text("Using layout Builder"),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: Colors.green.withOpacity(.3),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Text("Using MediaQuery"),
        )
      ],
    ));
  }
}
```

[image]

For size, you can use LayoutBuilder while the competent will be based on parent widget and it doesn't call the query. Somecases like on showDialog you need mediaQuery to get size. Use `LayoutBuilder` whenever possible.

- [creating-a-responsive-flutter-app](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive#creating-a-responsive-flutter-app)

More about [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) and [MediaQueryData/size](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQueryData/size.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your great answer and example. I have added also another questions that I appreciate if you could help also with them.

Comment: Didn't tested orientation, but it calls the build method by default, from this assumption layoutBuilder should be enough. If fails you can switch to MediaQuery, Use MediaQuery LayoutBuilder can't help.

Comment: @GoodMan you shouldn't add new questions to your existing question. Each question should be focused on one thing. If you have more questions write a new question for each of them